# Node slightly displaced in tikzfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to produce a simple subdivision of a line with:

```
    \draw (-6,0) -- (6,0) ; %edit here for the axis
    \foreach \x in  {-6,-4.5,-3,0,3,4.5,6} % edit here for the vertical lines
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
    \draw[shift={(-6,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_0 = a$};
    \draw[shift={(-4.5,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_1$};
    \draw[shift={(-3,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_2$};
    \draw[shift={(-1.5,0)},color=black] node[below] {$\cdots$};
    \draw[shift={(0,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_i$};
    \draw[shift={(1.5,0)},color=black] node[below] {$\cdots$};
    \draw[shift={(3,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_{N-2}$};
    \draw[shift={(4.5,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_{N-1}$};
    \draw[shift={(6,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_{N} = b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

but the right-most node appears annoyingly lower than the others. How can I fix it?

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={execute at begin node={\strut}}]`

Comment: Alternatively, just add `\strut` to every node text.

Comment: @AlphaRegion please see the answer below for a shorter version of the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the greater height of the b in the last node label, so perhaps the easiest fix is to `\smash` that one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-6,0) -- (6,0) ; %edit here for the axis
\foreach \x in  {-6,-4.5,-3,0,3,4.5,6} % edit here for the vertical lines
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\draw[shift={(-6,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_0 = a$};
\draw[shift={(-4.5,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_1$};
\draw[shift={(-3,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_2$};
\draw[shift={(-1.5,0)},color=black] node[below] {$\cdots$};
\draw[shift={(0,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_i$};
\draw[shift={(1.5,0)},color=black] node[below] {$\cdots$};
\draw[shift={(3,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_{N-2}$};
\draw[shift={(4.5,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_{N-1}$};
\draw[shift={(6,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$x_{N} = \smash{b}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See https://latexref.xyz/_005csmash.html#g_t_005csmash for more information on `\smash`ing.

Answer (score 2):

An edit of the (+1) excellent answer by @chsk making it significantly shorter in code

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-6,0) -- (6,0) ; %edit here for the axis
        \foreach \x/\y in  {-6/{$x_0 = a$},-4.5/{$x_1$},-3/{$x_2$},-1.5/{$\cdots$},0/{$x_i$},1.5/{$\cdots$},3/{$x_{N-2}$},4.5/{$x_{N-1}$},6/{$x_{N} =\smash{b}$}} % edit here for the vertical lines
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt)node[below] {\y};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: *excellent answer* Aw shucks. :) Thank you for the kind words!